# Accessing Annotation-value in advice

Tags: spring, annotations, aop

In my application I have methods annotated like this:

```
@SomeAnnotation(key1="value1", key2 ="value2")
public void myMethod()
```

I have defined the following apsect to perform some action on executing of those methods:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect()
{
    @Around("@annotation(my.package.SomeAnnotation)")
    public Object doSomething(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I would like to use the annotation values ("value1" and "value2" in the above example) inside my advice. What is the way to access the annotation at this point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@annotation` can be used in binding form, as follows:

```
@Around(value = "@annotation(a)", argNames = "a")
public Object doSomething(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, SomeAnnotation a)
    throws Throwable { ... }
```