# Getting annotation on AOP annotation pointcut

Tags: java, annotations, aop

I am trying to capture my annotation in an AOP pointcut like this (as seen on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282242/spring-aop-getting-parameters-of-the-pointcut-annotation)):

```
@After("@annotation(com.mypackage.annotation.Traza)")
        protected void logAnnotatedMethods(JoinPoint pjp, Traza traza) throws Throwable {
            LOGGER.info("It's here");
            LOGGER.info("Traza:" + traza);
        }
```

But I keep getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut` exception. If I remove the Traza parameter then it works and the pointcut is working wherever I annotate it with @Traza.

I know I can use reflection to obtain the annotation but shouldn't this be working too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone with the same problem, here's the solution:

```
@After("@annotation(traza)")
protected void logAnnotatedMethods(JoinPoint pjp, Traza traza) throws Throwable {
    LOGGER.info("It's here");
    LOGGER.info("Traza:" + traza);
}
```

That is, set the argument name to the @annotation bit in the @After annotation.